# Load ES5 modules directly using Systemjs without using babel transpiler

Tags: aurelia, systemjs, jspm

We have developed an application using aurelia. We have using typescript 2.1. We are configured the compiler target option to ES5. We are generating the source code in ES5 compatible. So we don't need the babel transpilation process. So how can we directly load the es5 modules in systemjs

`tsconfig.json`

```
 {
   "compilerOptions":
   {
     "module": "system",
     "experimentalDecorators": true,
     "noImplicitAny": false,
     "noEmitOnError": true,
     "removeComments": false,
     "sourceMap": true,
     "target": "es5",
     "lib": [
       "es2015",
       "es5",
       "es6",
       "dom"
     ]
   }
 }
```

Comment: SystemJS isn't tied to Babel in any way. You can check official Angular 2 plunk for SystemJS+TS example http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5

Comment: I assume you are using the [typescript-skeleton](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/releases/tag/1.1.2)? This doesn't use babel at all. My understanding is that babel transpiles ES6 to ES5, but typescript has its own transpiler. What do you see in your project that seems to indicate it is using babel?

Comment: As of now we are using  babel transpiler . We need to remove this transpiler

Comment: The code you show has nothing to do with babel, in config.js if you have set up a transpiler just set it to `none` I believe this will stop transpilation.  Also do not load babel in the app anywhere..

Comment: transpiler: "none" is not a valid option